# what will be soapAction which have urn?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I want to know what will be soapAction(url), if its given like :

```
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:technicalGetData" style="document"/>
```

i.e. : urn:technicalGetData

not able to fetch the responce & getting error

```
string(56) "<faultstring>Failed to submit the response</faultstring>"
```

I am using post method.

Pls guide,

Thanks

UPDATES : (client side calling part)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://blablabla/service');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8','SOAPAction: technicalGetData'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // 1 = for debugging purpose & 0 = production

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soaprequest);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: can you show us your code please

Comment: Which part you want to see?

Comment: the client side calling part

Comment: Pls see main comment , I have updated.
 
UPDATES : (client side calling part)

Comment: i can help you with soapclient as it is much simple and easy to use.if open to use soapclient give the wsdl url.

Comment: Sorry ! not allowed to give that url